# Can I read a spreadsheet directly from a file input?

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion

I have a form with an option to upload and process a spreadsheet.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
    <input type="submit" name="process" value="Process File" />
</form>
```

On post, I want to read the spreadsheet using a `cfspreadsheet action="read"`. Is there any way to read the spreadsheet directly from the form field, or do I have to upload it first using `cffile action="upload"` and then read it from the new file location?

Comment: Yes, technically you could use `<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#form.myFile#"  ..`> But can I ask why? The file is already on the server. So all you are saving is essentially a file `move` operation.

Comment: @Leigh - when I try that I get a FileNotFoundException. I just thought it would be simplest to just process the file directly. What would you suggest?

Comment: It works fine w/CF9. Skipping cffile does not really buy you anything. Keep in mind `action="upload"` is misleading. cffile does not actually upload anything. The file was already uploaded to the server. So all  `cffile` does is move that file from a temp directory to somewhere else, and rename it.

Comment: @Leigh - I'm using CF9, still getting a FileNotFoundException

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is often a generic error. It could also mean some problem accessing the file, like a permissions/sandbox error. Look at the full stack trace.

Comment: In other words, you need permission to access the temp directory where uploads are stored. But again, there is no real gain to skipping the `cffile` call.

Comment: I think that using #form.myFile# will only work if you are uploading to your local machine AND using IE. IE sends the full path to the file, so if CF is on the same machine, it can see the document and directly read it. Other browsers send just the filename, not the whole path, so the above doesn't work. You really need to be using <CFFile action="upload" to reliably get the file. Leigh's explanation of <CFFile action=upload is spot on, it's just moving/renaming the file, so the upload has already happened.

Comment: Actually, I believe `#form.myFile#` ends up containing the path to the uploaded file in the server's temporary directory ie `C:\the\server\tempdir\neotmpxxxxxxxxx.tmp`. So as long as the temp directory is accessible, cfspreadsheet can read it, just like any other spreadsheet on the server.

Comment: @Leigh - I think barnyr is correct, my form field seems to be storing only the file name. As the file does not exist in the current directory, it can't find it. But I will use a cffile upload....

Comment: @Leigh - correction; using form.myField as the src is working now, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before

Comment: @Leigh, you're right #form.myFile# contains the temp path the file is uploaded to. I think I was mistakenly remembering what happens when you don't set an enctype on the form. IE sends (or sent) the full path, so when developing locally you could access the file, but put when you come to test your code on another server it fails.

Comment: @barnyr - Yeah, I seem to remember something wacky like that. Though honestly I have never used #form.myFile# in production. It just feels a little too much like depending on a side effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following code reads the file directly from the form field / temp folder:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#form.myFile#" sheet="1" />
```

Comment: For next time - when you end up using a comment as an answer, it is nice to ask the poster to promote their comment to answer :P Just as a courtesy for helping :)

Comment: @Leigh - feel free to post it and I'll delete mine and accept yours :)